# What is a 'tree'?

Tags: word-meaning

Yesterday I read an interesting article about data mining. In this article was the word 'tree'. I looked it up in a dictionary, but the meaning didn't match to the sentence. So, any ideas what it could be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a term in a scientific field (computer science)

Comment: No, he's not asking that at all. Please, read his question carefully. He's just confused with the word "tree" used in a different context.

Comment: @CookieMonster He explicitly points to **Data Mining** and he should expect that the term has a specific definition in this field. Then one just can answer him by saying what it means in this field.

Comment: "He should expect"? Are you serious? How on Earth do you know what someone should or should not expect? That's just preposterous.

Comment: Look up _tree_ on [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=tree&ls=a). Then, check out the entries under the heading `Computing`. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, close it. It doen't really matter for me, because I have not much rep to lose and have my answer.

Comment: @user26754 No, enough people seem to agree with CM. This question's two more votes from reopening. And reopen it will.

Comment: @Araucaria OK, if you think so...

Comment: @Ahmad I think many people have been very supportive of your very subject specific - text specific even - answers. It'd be nice if you'd extend this same help to other users too :) After all, some of your questions ended up being interesting in the end.

Comment: @user26754 - Note that you do not lose any rep from having a question closed. It simply means no new answers can be added. People can still comment on and upvote a question, even when it's on hold.

Comment: Can we have a sentence that uses *tree* in the article you read?

Comment: @Araucaria Most of my questions are about grammar, word usage and sentence construction, though my example sentences are from scientific articles. But, I don't remember I have asked one to explain a term to me. I ask such questions in an appropriate website like (cs.stackexchange.com, programmer.stackexchange.....). Suppose that the OP or others continue to ask "what is a **node**, what is a **leaf**, what is a **branch**, what is a **tree's height**, what is a **tree's depth**, what is **null**, what is **pointer**,.... (I vote to close for the sake of the site), but you may know better...

Comment: @CookieMonster I don't know who removed my reply to your comment (which I got offended) while kept yours!. I told that's not preposterous, that's a logical expectation. IMHO he shouldn't expect in data mining 'tree' to mean a green plant that birds song over it, and needs to search or study a bit about basic concepts for such an specialized field. I don't about you!

Comment: @Ahmad If you say so, you could close _all_ questions because the topic is specializised and a little bit complicated and the OP could search for himself. But you don't, do you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An excerpt from a Wikipedia article reads:

> In computer science, a tree is a widely used abstract data type (ADT)—or data structure implementing this ADT—that simulates a hierarchical tree structure, with a root value and subtrees of children with a parent node, represented as a set of linked nodes.

You can read the full article following this link: [Tree (data structure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29)

A tree is also a mathematical structure commonly found in graph theory: [Tree (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29)

If you've done any Web programming before, you might have heard that the Document Object Model (the underlying structure of your Web pages) is commonly referred to as a tree and usually implemented as such. What this basically means is that all your HTML documents internally really look like an upside-down tree with the root part up at the top and the branches sprawling downward:

[image]

In other words, tree-like structures are all over the place in the world of computing.

Comment: This answer is _very_ good. imaginary +1 because I have not enought rep.

Answer (score 0):

In computer science it is a [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29). It is a rooted graph, which has no cycle.